# Rails undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass on collection_select - The reference called may be nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After reading through the other SO answers, it's pretty clear that there are some common themes.

Mostly this type of error seems to happen when the object called is not defined yet, but in this case we have a `has_many` relationship that may not have a referenced entry when building the selection.

```
Class Tag
  property :name, type: String
  has_many :in, :tagged, type: :CONCEPTUAL_TAG, model_class: :Artefact
end
```

One option is to do something like this:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :tagged_id %><br>

  <% if !@tag.tagged.empty? %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:tagged, Artefact.all.sort { |a,b| a.name <=> b.name }, :id, :name, options = {:prompt => "Please Select an Item", :selected => @tag.tagged.map(&:id)}, html_options = {:multiple => true, :class=>"search"}) %>
  <% else %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:tagged, Artefact.all.sort { |a,b| a.name <=> b.name }, :id, :name, options = {:prompt => "Please Select an Item"}, html_options = {:multiple => true, :class=>"search"}) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

But this is definitely not DRY.

Is there a way to select nothing when there is no association, and pre-populate when there is while keeping to a single `f.collection_select`?

Comment: Your question isn't as clear and straightforward as you seem to think. Could you try and update it with that you're trying to do, and what error you receive when you do it inside the text body?

Comment: At a meta level, I'm trying to come to a solution that I can use any time I want to offer a drop-down selection on a `has_many` relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use the condition in your view. Even if there are no items in `@tag.tagged`, it is still an `ActiveRecord::Relation` instance, so you can go ahead and just call `map` on it:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:tagged, 
  Artefact.all.sort { |a,b| a.name <=> b.name }, 
  :id,
  :name,
  options = {
    :prompt => "Please Select an Item",
    :selected => @tag.tagged.map(&:id)
  },
  html_options = {
    :multiple => true,
    :class=>"search"
  }) 
%>
```

Comment: Turns out this was a bug somewhere; when your answer made it clear that it was supposed to work as expected, I created a new app on a fresh vm, and it did work. Cheers.